# What is the difference between a DataSource and DataAdapter?

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, datasource, dataadapter

What is the difference between a DataSource and DataAdapter? I'm trying to decide if I should descend from IDataSource or IDataAdapter for code to be shared between Winforms and WebForms and I can't seem to figure out what the difference is other than slightly different ways to use them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? while they sound very similar, their usage differs greatly. for example datasources act as the repository, THE data, where as adapters act only as a delivery mechanism.

the majority of the code i have ever seen use data sources as the method for delivering content to a UI, and Adapters as the method of delivering data to a business object.

Comment: @N8 Well, I'd like to have my class as the thing used for delivering the data. Not, *the Data* so I guess DataAdapter would be for me, but my problem is that I don't want to directly connect to my database with it and IDataAdapter is almost exclusively based around SQL it seems

Answer (score 1):

DataSource is just source of data from where we are populating the data i.e. DataSet, DataBase, XML File, etc...

DataAdapter is tool or class using by which we can populate/update data from database.